# Connecting 12V WS2811 RGB LEDs to Arduino Uno & 5V Power Source (Breadboard needed?)

Tags: arduino-uno, led

I have an Arduino Uno, 12V WS2811 RGB LEDs (from Mokungit), a 5V power source, and DC power connector. I do not have a breadboard and hope I don't need one.

This is almost exactly what I need to follow [this tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Based-Stranger-Things-Lights/) to build a Stranger Things wall. The LED strip listed shares the same name as the one I have, but the wiring is different.

Here's a photo from the Instructables site:
[image]

However, the wires coming from my strip don't match up to the instructions, and I can't seem to figure out how to get these bad boys burning.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks to anyone who can help me get started!

Answer (score 2):

This image, from [here](http://MOKUNGIT%20WS2811%20Diffused%20Digital%20RGB%20LED%20Pixels%20Light%20Individually%20Addressable%20Round%20LED%20Pixels%20Module%2025.6ft%20DC12V%2012mm%20Waterproof%20IP68%20100pcs/set%20(Black)), shows which pins are what:

[image]

Note the flat *key* next to the 12 V and GND pins. In addition:

- the GND wire has a black broken line printed along it;
- the data line is in the middle.

If you trust the image then you should be able to wire them up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

That picture is for a 5 Volt rgb led strip. You have to use a 12 Volt power supply for your led and power the uno with another 5volt source. A computer power supply would be great for supplying power both 5 Volt and 12 Volt.

Answer (score 1):

The signals are clear on the bulb pcb. Take a multimeter in continuity mode and probe to see which pins on the round connector is DI, GND and +12v.

Then connect DI to the arduino. +12v to the strip. GND from the Arduino, LED strip and your +12v source should all be conected together.

Comment: Do you know where in the Arduino I should connect the DI?
I don't see how I can connect the +12V to the strip. The the round connector is the only one available.

Comment: You know how to use a multimeter in continuity test mode ? You need to probe each pins on the round connector with the pins on the 1st LED PCB to see which is which.

Once you know that you will know where to connect the Arduino and your +12v.

If you don't have a matching female round connector, I would cut it and use the direct wires. Or solder wires on the 1st LED PCB.

Comment: I don't know how to use a multimeter in continuity test mode. Also, I don't think I have a PCB. I assume this is nowhere nearly as straight-forward as the wiring in the Instructables instructions, eh?

Comment: Before launching into an electronics project I really suggest that you learn the basics like using a multimeter (and buy one, even a cheap one, if you don't have one). Here is a quick 2m video on how to do a continuity test with a multi-meter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOK8np4t40c

Without this basic skill you will not be able to complete your project.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I needed neither a multimeter nor the skills to use one in order to complete the project as it was described on the Instructables site. I should probably get one and learn how to use it, but I need to complete this today. Perhaps I won't be able to. It seems odd that having a different version of WS2811 would change the steps required so significantly.

Comment: Welcome to the world of electronics and proprietary connector pinout. 
Without testing which pins is which on the round connector, you have 2 chances out of 3 of applying +12v on the wrong pin and burning your entire LED strip.